# setting bin path for vim grep

Tags: vim, grep

**How can I set the path for grep?**

When I do grep, vim seems to be looking for `/bin/grep` but that doesn't exist on my system. It's in `/usr/bin/grep` instead.

Error from vim:

```
:!/bin/grep -nH sm 2>&1| tee /var/folders/fd/0cml_1kn237fdwnbfzfsrqqm0000gn/T/v6Hn2jM/11
[No write since last change]
zsh:1: no such file or directory: /bin/grep
(1 of 1): no such file or directory: /bin/grep
```

System:

- OSX 10.11.6
- MacVim 8.0 (119)

Answer (score 1):

in `~/.vimrc` add

`set grepprg=/usr/bin/grep`

seems to solve the problem.